# Chatterbot response from a specific database

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, chatterbot

I've trained my chatbot with my own corpus of conversations. But now I want ChatterBot to generate responses from another database (so I want this to be kinda conversation with a famous person so that every response is a citation). 
The only thing I could find is a *generate_response* method with a *conversation_id* parameter - but I'm pretty sure this is not what I'm looking for.

The best solution I have for now is to get_response and then find the closest (levenstein) sentence from my database. But this is definitely a poor way to solve this issue.

Does anyone know how can I deal with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way to train chatbot on the 'famous person citations' database because it's too small.

Comment: And one more thing - does it matter what storage adapter i use when talking about speed? I've tried the monogb but it has a limit of 16mb(